# How can I open up a fasta file in R studio without an error?

Tags: r, fasta

Hello I am trying to open a fasta file in R studio.
I am using the human MTHFR gene in FASTA format. My code to open it is

```
library("Biostrings")
myseq <- readDNAStringSet("MTHFR_sequence.fasta",format = "fasta")
```

but I keep getting an error from doing this. The error looks like :

```
Error in .Call2("new_input_filexp", filepath, PACKAGE = "XVector") : cannot open file 'MTHFR_sequence.fasta'
```

How can I fix this issue to open up the fasta file?

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question, but is the path correct? (i.e., same directory as R, indicated with `getwd()`). Is `file.exists("MTHFR_sequence.fasta")` true? If yes, can you open the file outside of R? (Is it a file-permissions thing?)

Comment: Not a stupid question at all. I think I might be having issues with the path. When I put the file.exist code, it returned false.

Comment: Okay, so that's what you need to fix. There are two strategies here: (1) point R to the absolute or relative path of the file, such as `readDNAStringSet("../../path/to/MTHFR_sequence.fasta",...)`; or (2) change R to that directory first, `setwd("../../path/to"); readDNAStringSet("MTHFR_sequence.fasta",...)`. I really prefer moving R to the directory of the project, assuming that all needed data files are within the project directory structure; for one-off files, I tend to deal with full paths.